# Ext.msg.Alert align text message in center

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to center the text message inside alert box?

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'Welcome to Sencha Fiddle!');
```

[image]

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

If I apply this to CSS then it works... But how can I apply it to the code?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of Ext.Msg.alert accepts HTML content, so you can use like this to center the message

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', '<p style="text-align:center">Welcome centered</p>');
```

Comment: Might be cleaner to define a new Ext.window with bodyStyle: 'text-align: center'.